# why am getting strange output "÷" when performing the simple follwoing c++ lines

Tags: c++, char, iostream, cout, unsigned

When running this code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Signed char
    signed char signedCharValue = -10;
    cout << "Signed char: " << signedCharValue << endl;

    // Unsigned char
    unsigned char unsignedCharValue = 246;
    cout << "Unsigned char: " << unsignedCharValue << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

i'm expecting:

```
Signed char: -10
Unsigned char: 246
```

i'm getting:

```
Signed char: ÷
Unsigned char: ÷
```

Comment: `char` is special. If you want the integer value you need to cast to an int.

Comment: Try this: `cout << "Signed char: " << +signedCharValue << endl;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because this is C++, not C.

`char` is a distinct type, and the `<<` operator that is used for the output has an overload for `char`, to output it as such.

If you want the codes, cast it to int.

```
cout << "Signed char: " << (int)signedCharValue << endl;
```